# Do locally created objects get released when their ViewController is dismissed?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm throwing up around 50 UIImageViews into a view via a loop, looks something like this (Photo is just my subclass):

```
Photo *photoImage = [[Photo alloc] initWithImage:photo];
[self.view addSubview:photoImage];
```

My current design flow uses the `presentViewController` and `dismissViewController` to move along views. When this I decide to dismiss this view, are these objects removed from memory and cleaned up? Also, are my array objects removed when the viewController is dismissed, or am I suppose to be using viewDidUnload?

I'm using ARC btw. Thanks

Comment: @Marvin I'm using arc though, not allowed to use release?

Comment: Ok dear...Its just my assumption

Comment: I would like to add something here. Why are u using 50 UIImageView.? Many complicated designs are achieved by using just 7 or 9 UIImageViews. So consider this point also.

Comment: @hpiOSCoder I'm building photo collages, so I need the effect of many photos on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

use Autorelease

Photo *photoImage = [[Photo alloc] initWithImage:photo]Autorelease];

[self.view addSubview:photoImage];

Comment: If I'm using ARC, is autorelease appropriate?

Comment: in ARC to release any object , objName=nil;